# Using Py2Exe without command line

Tags: python, executable, py2exe

Is it possible to compile a python script with py2exe without calling py2exe from the command line?

```
>Python setup.py py2exe
```

I'd like to run it all from a script, but haven't found a way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the beginig of the setup.py

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.argv.append("py2exe")
```

this way, if setup.py is called without args or with a double click, it will start the packaging